# Xib Instantiation of a custom UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

**Use-case:**

1. A Xib is defined with a single simple UIView
2. A custom view class was created ( inheriting from UIView )
3. In order to change the class used for the view defined @ [1] I change the XiB view identity from UIView to ~MyCustomView~

**Problem:**
I was expecting that 'MyCustomView::initWithFrame' will get called, apparently, it doesn't!!

How can I make custom classes instantiated while the 'XiB' is being loaded ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Use initWithNibName:bundle .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should override `initWithCoder:` for initialization and `awakeFromNib` for when view has all outlets and actions connected.